# Using solar power to create steam to spin turbine

Tags: solar-cell, solar-energy, windturbine

**Please read this question again now I have amended a glitch.**

The idea it to use a small solar panel to generate electricity, which will be sent to an element (or other device) which will heat up water producing steam. This steam will turn a turbine generating more electric than the solar panel would manage alone. This idea would be cheaper to setup than putting lots of solar panels on a house, and the electricity connection would be more stable.

It might be possible to take apart a kettle's element and make it run directly on DC, saving energy.

This journal covers a technique to produce steam without boiling water, three times faster. It says at the end of the article that Germany could use this with coal burners for power, so this could likely also be used to make my idea a reality:

https://www.nature.com/articles/srep23760

https://www.fastcompany.com/3059625/science-invents-a-better-way-to-boil-water

**Especially given that:**

> Wind is a more efficient power source than solar. Compared to solar
> panels, wind turbines release less CO2 to the atmosphere, consume less
> energy, and produce more energy overall. In fact, one wind turbine can
> generate the same amount of electricity per kWh as about 48,704 solar
> panels.

My idea is for home use, or for countries without much sun.

**Note:** I am happy to make small changes to my idea, such as using some type of chemical, another form of device etc...

**My question:** Since solar in the UK sucks, because the weather is rainy, would it perhaps be better to use a smaller solar panel which is used to heat up free* tap water producing steam to turn a turbine creating more electric than solar alone would be capable of? In the UK most houses pay a fixed price for an unlimited amount of water, and we could also use rain water.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: also, what's new about this? Solar ovens are a millenia old thing, and solar ovens for the heating of water for the purpose of producing electricity using a turbine is probably around 100 years old. [wikipedia has an article on it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concentrated_solar_power). More research!

Comment: @MarcusMüller My idea is: solar in the UK sucks because our weather sucks, why not use a smaller solar panel and turn free tap water into stream, producing more electricity than solar alone?

Comment: Have you done any calculations on the energy required to generate steam (and how you do that without boiling water?) and conversion efficiency of a small turbine / generator? How would running a kettle element on DC "save energy"?

Comment: @Transistor No, I was hoping my friends on Electronics Stack Exchange would give me a ball park estimate.

Comment: the ball park estimate is what you've already given: solar energy in the UK sucks. Adding more complicating steps can't increase efficiency. The opposite is true.

Comment: @MarcusMüller If solar gets 24v on a bad day, but my kettle needs just 5v, and will boil water three times faster based on those journal articles, maybe the output would be greater than the input? This assumes tap or rain water is free, and excludes initial setup costs.

Comment: "*... maybe the output would be greater than the input?*" This is impossible and defies the laws of thermodynamics. The articles are discussing generation of steam by direct solar - not solar electric.

Comment: I don't see anywhere in the articles that says steam is produced "three times faster". If it is, the key question is "three times faster than what?"

Comment: Also, I think you're confusing people by calling these "solar panels". Usually (at least around here) that term is used to mean a semiconductor device that converts light energy to electrical energy. In the first two articles you linked, that isn't what's going on. Instead, the solar energy is being reflected into an oil, which can heat to 555 C, and this oil is used to boil water to produce steam. Nowhere does it say steam is produced without boiling water.

Comment: Please read question again now a glitch has been amended. "three times better at turning water to steam than a bare stainless steel surface"

Comment: Too many false assumptions

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about free energy / perpetual motion / something-for-nothing daft ideas.

Comment: @securityauditor Why not just power the heater using the steam turbine, and skip the solar panel entirely?

Answer (score 6):

"The idea it to use a small solar panel to heat up water producing steam."

Nope. First sentence being wrong makes the rest of your obscure post not worth paying much attention to.

Small solar panels will have an efficiency on the order of 25% at best, while a direct heater such as a mirror, will have heating efficiencies on the order of 60 to 70%. So a thermal system will provide about 3 times as much energy per unit area as solar cells.

EDIT - I was asked to check an "updated" question.

The answer is still no. And the update makes no more sense than the original.

> Since solar in the UK sucks, because the weather is rainy, would it
> perhaps be better to use a smaller solar panel which is used to heat
> up free* tap water producing steam to turn a turbine creating more
> electric than solar alone would be capable of? In the UK most houses
> pay a fixed price for an unlimited amount of water, and we could also
> use rain water.

Question - why do you think a solar panel is not "solar" (as in "solar in the UK sucks"). If the weather is rainy, why do you think that a solar panel will produce any energy? Did you miss the "solar" part of "solar cell"?

Furthermore, any useful steam turbine will be a sealed cycle, so the amount of water used will, in the long run, be very, very small, and the price of water will make no difference.

Since my original answer apparently did not register, let be be explicit.

Direct (thermal) solar energy collection is about 3 times more efficient than a solar cell. This means that, for the same collector area and weather, 3 times as much steam can be heated directly as by solar panels. This means that a directly (thermally) driven steam turbine will produce 3 times as much power as one driven by solar panels.

The answer to your question remains no.

Edit 2 -

Additionally, you have misunderstood the conditions being explored in the paper you cite. The nanoparticle treatment they discuss produces results in the marginal power regime where nucleation sites are the limiting factor in bubble production. This would correspond to the condition where normally the water is not quite boiling, and small bubbles which cling to the side of the kettle/pot are seen. Under these circumstances, the surface under discussion will produce many more bubbles, and the energy carried away in the steam in these bubbles will increase the heat flow through the walls of the vessel.

However, in power generation regimes, equivalent to a rolling boil, bubble formation is not limited by availability of nucleation sites, so the new surface will not make a noticeable difference.

Comment: Please check my updated question.

Comment: @securityauditor really not getting any better. WhatRoughBeast hit the proverbial nail on its head: your assumptions that you somehow magically can get more energy out of a solar-powered system than the sun puts into it is completely impossible.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Check my reply to user1850479 below, and reply there.

Comment: @WhatRoughBest Whilst I respect your reply, I do not respect your tone, but I understand things can be misunderstood online. Regardless, I doubt with UK weather we would be able to do direct (termal) solar energy. Instead, charging a DC battery with a solar cell and using that solar cell to create energy from steam if/when required might be a better solution.

Comment: @securityauditor - Sorry for the tone, if blunt upsets you. Nonetheless, you persist in your error. Why, exactly,would solar cells work in the UK when "direct" won't? You keep saying you think it will without any justification. Your comment to 1850479 says, "I probably cannot heat water from the sun, so I need to use a solar cell to charge a battery". And that is simply wrong. Power is power. If you don't have enough to heat water, you don't have enough to charge a battery. Solar cells are not magic energy-producing devices. Also. see Edit 2.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast Check my reply, and the one before, on the other answer.

Answer (score 2):

> The idea it to use a small solar panel to generate electricity, which will be sent to an element (or other device) which will heat up water producing steam. This steam will turn a turbine generating more electric than the solar panel would manage alone.

This is fundamentally a poorly thought out idea. Energy is a conserved quantity, so at each step of the process you get less energy out then you started with.  For example, if each of your generation steps is 20% efficient, and you start with 100w of sunlight, you get 20w at the first solar panel, and then 4W out of the steam generator.  You've essentially just invented a way to ruin your solar output.

A better idea:  if you don't have enough sunlight to make solar energy work, do not use solar energy.

Comment: But if I can produce 3 times as much steam by following that journal article that would be 4W * 3 = 12W which is a significant improvement. Then we need to understand I would not use a kettle element, but another product to heat water (suggestions please?) which can be taken apart to run directly from DC further reducing the energy drain. By this point we are potentially at 15W, and with improvements along the way we can surpass the 20W of the first panel. It might require some type of chemical, or aerodynamic design, but I am sure we can do it :-).

Comment: @securityauditor  Adding heat to water is already close to 100% efficient, so further improvement is not possible. You're just misunderstanding that article which is not related to your question.

Comment: But if I live in rainy UK I probably cannot heat water from the sun, so I need to use a solar cell to charge a battery for when the energy is needed. I would agree with you if we lived in Egypt or something...

Comment: @securityauditor If you do not have sunlight then you do not have solar energy.  This is a simple and obvious conclusion, and one that should have taken at most a few moments of thought on your part to realize, not a dozen replies. I think at this point you are trying not to face reality, but that is a foolish thing to do.  The real world will beat you down and force you to acknowledge it.

Comment: @user1850479 I guess securityauditor means the temperature doesn't get hot enough to boil water, on a cloudy day, but a solar panel still produces ***some*** power, which can then be used to boil water if you insulate the heater well enough.

Comment: @user253751 Exactly, and maybe by using that article which produces steam three times faster we might end up with more energy than the solar panel alone could produce?

Comment: @securityauditor See my answer from last week where I addressed this.

Comment: @securityauditor Why would you need a solar panel then? Just plug a battery into the heater, and plug a bigger battery into the turbine, and let the smaller battery recharge the bigger battery. Then swap them around and let the bigger battery recharge a bigger bigger battery. Repeat several times until you have all the power you need.

Comment: @user253751 Great idea, if it is actually possible. I still prefer to use solar so it is all "free" energy, aside from wasting some sea water... Based on the answers I assume it would not work though :-(.

Comment: @securityauditor Well you could charge the first battery from solar. You could even have a little solar panel and then several heaters and turbines in a series, and you could power the entire planet from one solar panel!

Comment: @user253751 Ha ha ha funny.

Comment: @securityauditor It's not funny. It's serious. If you had a machine that could put out more power than the amount of power you put in, you could just connect a bunch of them together and make infinite power.